# HTTPS Connection Times out after Tomcat 8 SSL Config

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I've never set up SSL/TLS before, it's not working, and I have no idea how to debug it. Intial googling is not turning up options. Here's what i've done:

1. used openSSL to generate a private key and CSR

   openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
2. gotten my csr signed and downloaded the certificates from startssl.com (free for first year)
3. installed the root, intermediate, and my domain cert into the .keystore like:

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file root.crt -keystore .keystore

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file intermediate.crt -keystore .keystore

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file mydomain.crt -keystore .keystore
4. added the tomcat connector (shown below but i had to remove the xml angle braces or stack overflow wouldnt display it)

   Connector  SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100"     clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"       enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
      port="8443" keystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/.keystore"           keystorePass="password"    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"       scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
5. bounced tomcat, server starts successfully and serves http requests
6. opened catalina.out to see the following error

   > java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key
   >   entry
7. I was advised to create a .pkcs12 file by concatenating the root an intermediate certs and then using the command below

   openssl pkcs12 -in mydomain.crt -certfile CA.crt -chain -inkey privateKey.key -out tomcat.p12
8. Unfortunately this resulted in the following error:

> 4294956672:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong
>   tag:tasn_dec.c:1201: 4294956672:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type
>   =PKCS12

9. Then I tried to concatenate the private key, domain, intermediate, and root certificate into one .pem file, and then convert it to a x509
10. I then tried to use the x509 cert in jks & tomcat but i got the same error

> java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry

Reading up on this via google makes me more confused - i read these extremely confident tutorials on how to do this and they appear to have been dead wrong. Where can I find an accurate guide on how to set this up.

Comment: Ok, good, that's what I was reading. I tried to create the pkcs12 and got some error about cert chains and I haven't had time to work past that one yet. The one guide I saw said to use the openssl root cert but it's no longer bundled with open ssl.

Answer (score 2):

1. concatenate PEM format cert chain.

   > cat 2_host.domain.net.crt 1_Intermediate.crt CA.crt  > fullchain.crt
2. convert PEM format fullchain to PKCS12

   > openssl pkcs12 -export -out tomcat.p12 -inkey ../ssh.key -in fullchain.crt
3. check tomcat.pk12

   > keytool -list -keystore tomcat.p12 -storetype PKCS12
   >   keytool -list -keystore tomcat.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -v
4. convert PKCS12 to PKS

   > keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias 1 -destkeystore tomcat.jks -deststoretype JKS -destalias tomcat
5. tomcat server.xml file

```xml
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional"
           keystoreFile="tomcat.jks"
           keystoreType="JKS"
           keystorePass="mypass"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

6. test tomcat config

   > configtest.sh

Comment: 2_host.domain.net.crt 1_Intermediate.crt  CA.crt are got from startssl.com

Comment: configtest.sh is quite an important thing to know!

Answer (score 0):

The entries you have imported are *certificates* - for this to work you need to have the private key as well.

To correctly set this up, you will need to utilize something like openssl's PKCS12 functionality to create a PKCS#12 format archive then import THAT into a JKS file (.keystore) containing the contents of the PKCS#12.

You may need to concatenate mydomain.crt+intermediate.crt first.

**EDIT**

To hopefully make this more clear:

1. Concatenate intermediate.crt+root.crt from the CA as provided into one file CA.crt
2. Run openssl pkcs12 -in mydomain.crt -certfile CA.crt -chain -inkey privateKey.key -out tomcat.p12

Once that is completed you can verify using keytool as

keytool -list -keystore tomcat.p12 -storetype PKCS12

If you see it as privateKeyEntry - you're most of the way there.

keytool -list -keystore tomcat.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -v

will list the entry certificate and any chain information. If that spits out your cert + the chain (should be 3 entries in the one alias) you can then import it to a JKS file.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias 1 -destkeystore tomcat.jks -deststoretype JKS -destalias tomcat

Follow the prompts and you should be complete.

**EDIT 2**

Order of the certificates is important - 
cat mydomain.crt intermediate.crt root.crt > full-chain.crt

The following may possibly help
openssl pkcs12 -certfile full-chain.crt -chain -inkey privateKey.key -out tomcat.p12

Comment: Lol, see comment I accidentally posted above. The CA gave me a root, intermediate, and domain cert. Should I concatenate those together to make the pkcs12?

Comment: This seems so simple but it seems every step fails? I concatenated root.crt and intermediate.crt copy/pasting the contents together in a textpad. I tried with and without the begin and end certificate tags. Then I ran the command and got the following:    $ openssl pkcs12 -in domain.com.crt -certfile concat.crt -chain -inkey privateKey.key -out tomcat.p12
4294956672:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1201:
4294956672:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type=PKCS12

Comment: I'll convert this to a chat when I get to work keep an eye out

Comment: I won't get to try any other fixes until tonight after work. (This is for a personal project).

Comment: After starting from scratch I'm stuck in a new way now. If you can continue to help i'd really appreciate it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052805/configured-ssl-on-tomcat-8-and-connection-times-out

Comment: Saw you got that resolved - If the cert pack is correct and this answer helped please accept. And I was going to say almost immediately that 443 on modern linux systems is almost always closed by default :-)

Comment: I wasn't ever able to get the cert pack built, so I started from scratch and generated my private key and csr from the key tool..I think I messed something up when creating the private key and it was blocking everything bit I'm not sure what I did wrong exactly. I think if I could have created the pkcs12 that would have helped fix it.

Comment: I only got it right by going to startssl.com support and getting their instructions for the whole process